# Wrong append in the PyQt app algorithm, works well while testing in different setting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, pyqt

I'm writing an application for automatic emails sending through outlook. I've created simple algorithm for extracting data and composing it into email body. If someone wants to place some variables in the email body then they have to surround copied names of `self.data: pd.DataFrame` columns with: `<<variable_name>>` signs - regex then finds the variables, and their positions in the text and replaces them in algorithm with real data from DataFrame.

**However I stumbled upon a problem**: the algorithm works fine outside the PyQt app but not within the application. The problem is that outside the app algorithm creates as many email messages as there are rows in DataFrame (as planned) but in application it creates just one message composed of data from the first row. I've tried debugging it and so far I can confirm that the loop goes as planned through all the rows of DataFrame but for unknown for me reason it appends just the first message to the list. I have created some dummy data to replicate work of algorithm:

```
import pandas as pd
# Dummy data for loop:
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Hello':['++++++','======'],'Welcome':[';;;;;;','------'],'Hi':['!!!!!!', '??????']})
content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis viverra odio, sagittis malesuada'
content_string = list(content)
positions = [[1, 4], [10, 14], [30, 36]]
variables = ['Hello', 'Welcome', 'Hi']

emails = []
# Composing email message for each user. One user == one row of pd.DataFrame
for x in range(len(df)):
    for num, (position, var) in enumerate(zip(positions, variables)):
        if var in df.columns:
            content_string[position[0]:position[1]] = str(df[var][x])
            email_composed = ''.join(content_string)
            if num + 1 == len(variables):
                emails.append(email_composed)
                content_string = list(content)
for i in emails:
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

`L++++++m i;;;;;; dolor sit ame!!!!!!sectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis viverra odio, sagittis malesuada`

`L======m i------ dolor sit ame??????sectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis viverra odio, sagittis malesuada`

**And here is the same piece of code within the PyQt5 application:**

**Functional part:** file `outlook.py`

```
import re
import sys
import traceback
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from outlook_window import Ui_MainWindow


class OutlookForm(QMainWindow, QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.actionOpen_data_file.triggered.connect(self.load_data)
        self.ui.list_widget_columns.itemClicked.connect(self.get_clicked_item_from_list)
        self.ui.list_selected_variables.itemClicked.connect(self.get_clicked_item_from_list_of_variables)
        self.ui.push_button_add_variable.clicked.connect(self.add_data_to_listed_variables)
        self.ui.push_button_clean_list.clicked.connect(self.clear_list_of_selected_items)
        self.ui.push_button_send.clicked.connect(self.send_email)
        self.data = None
        self.separator: str = ';'
        self.show()

    def load_data(self) -> None:
        try:
            file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "All files (*);;CSV files (*.csv)")
            if file:
                if len(self.separator) != 0:
                    self.data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=str(self.separator))
                else:
                    self.data = pd.read_csv(file)
                self.clean_data_from_data_frame()
                self.ui.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setColumnCount(self.data.shape[1])
                self.ui.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setRowCount(self.data.shape[0])
                for column, key in enumerate(self.data.columns):
                    for row, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                        new_item = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                        self.ui.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setItem(row, column, new_item)
                self.ui.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.data.columns)
                self.load_columns_to_list_of_variables()
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', 'Database successfully loaded!')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', f'Something went wrong: {traceback.format_exc()}')

    def clean_data_from_data_frame(self) -> None:
        self.data = self.data.dropna(axis=1)
        self.data.columns = self.data.columns.str.rstrip()
        for column, data_type in zip(self.data.columns, self.data.dtypes):
            if data_type == 'object' or data_type == 'str':
                self.data[column] = self.data[column].str.strip()

    def load_columns_to_list_of_variables(self) -> None:
        if isinstance(self.data, pd.DataFrame):
            self.ui.list_widget_columns.clear()
            for column in self.data.columns:
                self.ui.list_widget_columns.addItem(column)

    def get_clicked_item_from_list(self, item) -> Any:
        item_from_list = self.ui.list_widget_columns.currentItem().text()
        return item_from_list

    def get_clicked_item_from_list_of_variables(self, item) -> Any:
        item_from_list = self.ui.list_selected_variables.currentRow()
        return item_from_list

    def add_data_to_listed_variables(self, item) -> None:
        item_from_list = self.get_clicked_item_from_list(item)
        self.ui.list_selected_variables.addItem(item_from_list)

    def clear_list_of_selected_items(self) -> None:
        self.ui.list_selected_variables.clear()

    def get_variables_from_list(self) -> list:
        variables_from_list = []
        for i in range(self.ui.list_selected_variables.count()):
            variables_from_list.append(self.ui.list_selected_variables.item(i).text())
        return variables_from_list

    def get_data_from_dataframe(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        variables_from_list = self.get_variables_from_list()
        columns_to_slice_from_df = []
        for variable in variables_from_list:
            if variable in self.data.columns:
                columns_to_slice_from_df.append(variable)
        sliced_df = self.data[columns_to_slice_from_df]
        return sliced_df

    @property
    def find_matching_patterns_from_text(self) -> Any:
        sequence = r'<<(.*?)>>'
        pattern = re.compile(pattern=sequence)
        email_body = self.ui.text_edit_email_body.toPlainText()
        variables = re.findall(pattern, email_body)
        positions = pattern.finditer(email_body)
        return variables, positions

    def create_list_of_mails_messages(self):
        list_of_mails = []
        sliced_data_frame = self.get_data_from_dataframe()
        variables_from_list, positions = self.find_matching_patterns_from_text
        email_body = self.ui.text_edit_email_body.toPlainText()
        email_body_list = list(email_body)
        for row in range(len(sliced_data_frame)):
            for num, (position, variable) in enumerate(zip(positions, variables_from_list)):
                if variable in sliced_data_frame.columns:
                    email_body_list[position.start():position.end()] = str(sliced_data_frame[variable][row])
                    email_composed = ''.join(email_body_list)
                    if num + 1 == len(variables_from_list):
                        list_of_mails.append(email_composed)
                        email_body_list = list(email_body)
        return list_of_mails

    def get_email_addresses(self) -> list:
        column_with_addresses = self.ui.line_edit_addresses.text()
        list_of_addresses = self.data[column_with_addresses].to_list()
        return list_of_addresses

    def send_email(self):
        list_of_emails = self.create_list_of_mails_messages()
        list_of_addresses = self.get_email_addresses()
        for address in list_of_addresses:
            print(address)
        for mail in list_of_emails:
            print(mail)

    #        Here are other actions responsible for connecting to outlook -
    #        - not necessary for understanding the issue in MRE


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = OutlookForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Layout part:** file: `outlook_window.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(869, 897)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../static/img/email_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName("gridLayout_6")
        self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 300))
        self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(850, 300))
        self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setObjectName("table_widget_data_from_data_frame")
        self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setColumnCount(0)
        self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.table_widget_data_from_data_frame, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.text_edit_email_body = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_edit_email_body.setObjectName("text_edit_email_body")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.text_edit_email_body, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_6.addLayout(self.gridLayout_5, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(60, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.push_button_send = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_button_send.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.push_button_send.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.push_button_send.setObjectName("push_button_send")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.push_button_send, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_6.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.push_button_clean_list = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_button_clean_list.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.push_button_clean_list.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        self.push_button_clean_list.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.push_button_clean_list.setObjectName("push_button_clean_list")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.push_button_clean_list, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.push_button_add_variable = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_button_add_variable.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.push_button_add_variable.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        self.push_button_add_variable.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.push_button_add_variable.setObjectName("push_button_add_variable")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.push_button_add_variable, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.list_widget_columns = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.list_widget_columns.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.list_widget_columns.setObjectName("list_widget_columns")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.list_widget_columns, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 16777215))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.list_selected_variables = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.list_selected_variables.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.list_selected_variables.setObjectName("list_selected_variables")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.list_selected_variables, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_6.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.line_edit_addresses = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_edit_addresses.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 16777215))
        self.line_edit_addresses.setObjectName("line_edit_addresses")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.line_edit_addresses, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(150, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem2, 2, 6, 1, 3)
        self.label_addresses = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_addresses.setObjectName("label_addresses")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_addresses, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(5, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_6.addLayout(self.gridLayout_4, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 869, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_data_file = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_data_file.setObjectName("actionOpen_data_file")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_data_file)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.push_button_send.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send "))
        self.push_button_clean_list.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clean"))
        self.push_button_add_variable.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Columns"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selected variables"))
        self.list_selected_variables.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_addresses.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column with addresses:"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen_data_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open data file"))
        self.actionOpen_data_file.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+N"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is a link to .csv file with some dummy data to load to table widget, and a .txt file with "Lorem ipsum" e-mail message, with variables from .csv data already in the text between <<>> signs:

https://github.com/youngTouring/outlook-data.git

**In order to reproduce the behavior you have to:**

- start `outlook.py` application
- load `MOCK_DATA.csv` using ctrl + N shortcut or action on the top-left ("Open data file")
- using "Add" button add 3 variables to the list on the right ("Selected variables"): I already typed down <<**first_name**>> <<**last_name**>> and <<**gender**>> in the .txt file, so the best option is to chose these 3
- type in "email" in the line edit near label which says "Column with addresses:"
- copy and paste email message to plain text widget at the bottom of the application from `email_body.txt`
- click "Send" button and watch the output in python console - current behavior is only one email message appended to the list. Correct behavior would be all mail messages in the list.

So the output is just the first message appended to the list. I'm not sure if I included all the code necessary to understand the issue. If someone suspects what may be the cause of such behavior I'd appreciate some sugestions.

Comment: Isn't `find_matching_patterns_from_text` missing the parentheses (and arguments)? If, instead, it's correct, we need to know what does it return and what `get_data_from_dataframe` does, so please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Yes, `find_matching_patterns_from_text ` missing parentheses becauseit is a `@property`, sorry I forget to include that. I'v edited the code and added `find_matching_patterns_from_text ` and `get_data_from_dataframe `.

Comment: Please, take your time to provide a complete MRE, including a sample csv data. It should be some code we can easily copy, paste and run, possibly without substantial modifications. We shouldn't focus on trying to understand how to reproduce the problem, but on finding its solution.

Comment: I've rearranged the issue - I included all the code neccasary for the MRE. I also added link to some dummy data - both for email_message and for some .csv data which you can load to the table widget. I'm hope that it works fine, I've tested this "minimal" version and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the issue: the problem was caused by regex and its iter positions from text. I'm not sure why but start and end positions extracted from regex iterated in wrong way during creation of email messagesin algorithm. I've changed the script and added function which turns regex iter positions into python list. When algorithm iterates over a list it works fine. I don't know why for loop acts in such weird way with regex positions but replacing them with list works fine so I think that it closes this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).